# $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{2i}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x} \, dx$, why?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How comes this true?

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin x} x \, dx = \frac{1}{2i}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ix}-1} x \, dx$$

Comment: Do you know the complex exponential form of $\sin$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\displaystyle\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x} \, dx$ is not well-defined, in fact
$$\frac{e^{ix}-1} x=\frac{\cos(x)-1} x+\frac{i\sin(x)} x$$
$x\mapsto\dfrac{\sin(x)} x$ is an even function, therefore
$$\frac{1}{2i}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{i\sin(x)} x \, dx=\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin x} x \, dx$$
$x\mapsto\dfrac{\cos(x)-1} x$ is an odd function, but its integral is divergent, because $$\int^M_{0} \frac{\cos(x)-1} x \, dx=\left[\frac{\sin(x)-x} x\right]_{0}^{M}+\int^M_{0} \frac{\sin(x)-x} {x^2} \, dx=A-\int^M_{1}\frac{1} {x}dx$$
where A is finite but $\displaystyle\int^M_{1}\frac{1} {x}dx$ is divergent when $M\to\infty$.

Comment: are you sure $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}dx$ is well-defined ?

Comment: @user1952009 No problem at 0, integration by parts at infinity.

Comment: @user1952009 Well...I think it cannot be well-defined, you are right.

Comment: OP's formula is true  in the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty = \lim_{A \to \infty} \int_{-A}^A$ sense